# How do I get Express to render HTML after a post request?

Tags: javascript, express

I am getting started with creating a node server with Express and I have run into the following problem:  It seems that I cannot respond to POST requests with new views.

Here is the simplified code snippet for context:

```
 app.get('/admin/dashboard', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/admin/dashboard.html')))
 app.post('/admin/dashboard',(req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/admin/dashboard.html')))
```

When I type in `/admin/dashboard` into the address bar of my browser, the expected GET request is made to my server and the correct view is rendered. That makes me happy.

However, when I make a post request to the same URL (via clicking on a form submit button), the same view is not rendered.

I am most likely missing some fundamental point here.  Why is the view not rendered with a post request?

Comment: I can see my browser is receiving the correct file when I check out the "network" tab in my browser, but for some reason, the browser does not render it.

Comment: Have you tried `res.render()` ?

Comment: That didn't work either, unfortunately.  The browser is receiving HTML from the server, but it is not rendered.  I am starting to think  that browsers just don't render HTML returned from fetch POST requests?